# Disk fragmentation on Linux

Tags: linux, defragment, fat32, ext3

Do I have to de-fragment my ext3 and FAT32 filesystems on Linux? And if yes how?

Comment: did my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes to FAT32, no to ext3. See [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=26628) for tools that can do it.

Comment: ext3 does fragment (All rewritable filesystems do), but ext3 is much better at avoiding high fragmentation levels than FAT32, so chances are you'll never hit a noticeable performance penalty anyway.

Comment: @TuxRug Unless, of course, you eat up around 90%+ of your disk. But you have bigger problems at that point...

Comment: @oneat, marking this as the answer would be appreciated.